# Springcloud bus custom messages cannot be sent through rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

When using the springcloud bus, a custom message is created and sent through `rabbitmq`, but after the message is sent, it does not go to `rabbitmq`. When you try to `call /actuator/bus-refresh`, you can see the bus messages emitted from the console page of rabbitmq.

I tried to start a micro service to register a custom event listener but failed to receive it. However, if the sender registers a listener himself, he can receive it but does not send it from `rabbitmq`.

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

About `@RemoteApplicationEventScan` annotations, I code all under the same package, so I should be able to scan to `TestEvent`. I also tried to specify `basepackage`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RemoteApplicationEventScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @RequestMapping("test")
    public String test() {

        final TestEvent testEvent = new TestEvent(this, context.getId(), null,"test");
        context.publishEvent(testEvent);
        return "success";
    }
}
```

```
@Data
public class TestEvent extends RemoteApplicationEvent {

    private String action;


    public TestEvent(Object source, String originService, String destinationService, String action) {
        super(source, originService, destinationService);
        this.action = action;
    }
}
```

When I called `http://localhost:8080/actuator/bus-refresh` I can see the information in the `rabbitmq`.

```
{" type ":" AckRemoteApplicationEvent ", "timestamp" : 1554350325406, "originService" : "application: 0: b3461fbec3536203a7020ff9d24bb11b", "destinationService" : "* *", "id" : "e6b875bd - 2402-494 - f - a870 - 4917324 d2c5c ackId ", "" :" af93075e - 55 d2-41 f8 - ba27 - e3c80cf19eea ", "ackDestinationService" : "* *", "the event" is: "org. Springframework. Cloud. Bus. Event. RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent"}.
```

But when I call to `http://localhost:8080/test/test`, I don't.

Comment: Sorry，My English is not very good, please understand, I am using the translation，This is the first time I use stackoverflow. Please give me more advice

Answer (score 0):

I came into the same issue a few days ago and it turned out that it was because the `originService` was incorrect. passing in `context.getId()` as `originService` doesn't work.

Short answer: use `org.springframework.cloud.bus.BusProperties#id`. You can inject `BusProperties` to your component. Or you can configure your own spring cloud bus id as stated in the [document](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_addressing_an_instance).

I am not 100% sure this is the proper way. Maybe I missed something in the document. It is just based on what I read from the source code of `org.springframework.cloud.bus.BusAutoConfiguration`, method [acceptLocal](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-bus/blob/a531a3907813d7f337fa34295c19b306f8d576f6/spring-cloud-bus/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/bus/BusAutoConfiguration.java#L144).

Hope it works for you.